# Search for text mysql database is really slow

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I have a table on mySql with around 300,000 records. One column is a VARCHAR and it contains a link (let's say, http://www.mysite.com/123012993)

Using Java, everytime I create a new record I need to know if it already exists. The exact link must be on the database. If it's new, then proceed to insert. Else, do nothing.

So I have the following:

```
String selectString = "Select count(link) from records_table where link = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectString);
ps.setString(1, "http://www.mysite.com/123012993");
ResultSet rsFinding = ps.executeQuery();

rsFinding.next();

if (t != 0) return false;
else { // do normal insert }
```

However, the query to search the Text is very slow, we are talking around 1 minute. The insert itself is very fast. Everything runs on localhost.

Is this the right way to search for the text? Or should I index the database?

I was thinking on implementing a hashkey and narrow the results, but a query on 300,000 records shouldn't be to heavy I believe.

Thanks

Comment: an index would help. there's not much point in building a hash yourself, since indexes already do that (somewhat) in the background anyways.

Comment: For anything that isn't a mass-result table scan an index should be used in most cases for lookups.

Comment: Another option is to always attempt the insert and add a unique constraint on `link`. You can catch and ignore the `SQLException` thrown from the insert when there is a duplicate.

Comment: @samlewis: That's too dirty. The SQLException is rather stupid and you'd have no way to tell if the insert failed or the connection broke or whatever. Parsing the message is too fragile.

Comment: I created the index and unfortunately there was no change on the performance. I know it's not a server issue, as I see the server utilization and CPU is at 30%, RAM the same.

Comment: @maaartinus It is not too dirty if you check that `SQLException.getSQLState()` returns `23000` which will only be the case for a duplicate key: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-error-sqlstates.html Nice answer btw.

Comment: @samlewis: I'm not sure... it's listed there with `ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW` and `ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED` as well, whatever this means. But yes, this is something I could live with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- `PreparedStatement` should not be prepared each time again and again. Prepare and reuse.
- Your `t` is defined nowhere.
- Let the DB do the work: I guess each DB has a possibility to handle duplicates. For MySql there's [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

So use this command

`INSERT ? INTO records_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link = link`

The part `link = link` is a no-op to make the syntax looking good for the MySql parser.

There's also `INSERT IGNORE` which is bit easier to use (no need for the no-op), but it ignores more problems, which is bad.

I forgot to mention that you need a unique key constraint on `link` (a primary key is a special case of UK as thus fine too).

Comment: Great, good advice everyone. 
@Maaartinux yes you are right with some semantics errors, I copied it from a code, but I am glad you got the general idea.

Now I need to work on the unique constrain, as my link column was defined as VARCHAR(1000) and it only applies to fields up to 255

Comment: If you really need such a long column, then create another one used as UK and store there a checksum (MD5 should do). Or `ADD UNIQUE KEY (link(200), link_checksum)`. The former part makes it sort of sorted (with things behind column 200 being ignored) while the latter makes it work.

Comment: OK I forgot to ask. I have defined the LINK field as unique. however, it is not the primary key (there's an id field as well).

Using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, how can I make sure the field you are comparing for existance is LINK, instead if ID?

Comment: All constraints get checked, so it'll work (assuming the ID is autogenerated, it won't conflict, so the only conflict can come from `link`).

Comment: Yes, mySql will check all constrains. Thanks, this helped a lot.